# Python 3.x OOP, Inheritance after an object has already been defined

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance

this is the code.

```
class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.alive = "alive"
    self.good = "good"
    self.eyecolor = "varys"


sally = Animal()

sally.eyecolor = "brown"


class Canine(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
     super(Canine,self).__init__()
     self.legs = 4
     self.fur = "everywhere"
 sally = Canine()
 print(sally.eyecolor)
```

So in this scenario, I have a class, and an object constructed by it, **sally**. Now I have a new class, *Canine* I would like to move **sally** into. Is there a way I can move sally into the *Canine* class so she retains her original eyecolor?

- I am aware I can just do **sally**.eyecolor = "brown" again, however, in the real problem I have many more attributes and doing that for each is cumbersome.
- I was thinking copy.deepcopy(**sally**), but I'm not sure how I would then put her through a class instance to inherit the new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a class method such as `Canine.from_animal` that allows to do so.

You are probably thinking of doing this because casting from one type to another is something often seen. By example, you probably did this in the past.

```
x = float(1) # 1.0
```

So why couldn't you just do this?

```
canine = Canine(some_animal)
```

The answer is that Python does not just infer how to cast a class to another, even when it is a subclass. This behaviour has to be defined by some method.

By example, if you want to cast a class object to a `float`, you must have defined the `__float__` special method.

The natural conlusion that follows from this is that you need to implement your own class method to get an object of type `Canine` from an object of type `Animal`.

```
class Canine(Animal):

    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_animal(cls, animal):
        canine = cls()
        canine.eyecolor = animal.eyecolor

        # Implement any additional logic here

        return canine

sally = Animal()

sally.eyecolor = "brown"

sally = Canine.from_animal(sally) # Sally knows where she stands now
```

Note that there is nothing that prevents you defining the method `to_canine` in the class `Animal` instead.

```
class Animal(object):

    ...

    def to_canine(self):
        canine = Canine()
        canine.eyecolor = self.eyecolor
        return canine
```